# Are there any constraints on the undefined behavior caused by signed integer overflow?

Tags: c++, gcc

Signed integer flow produces undefined behavior in C++. However, in practice, what is the nature of this undefined behavior? Is it limited to an undefined value of the result? Or can it do arbitrary things like changing other variables or even the control flow of the program?

Comment: Undefined Behaviour - means the behaviour of your program can not be analysed or predicted. Among other things, the compiler is allow to note the undefined behaviour and remove the branch of code that contains it https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub .  It can even cause Time Travel - https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: "In practice" the value usually comes out as if the operands were first cast to unsigned then, after the operation, the result is cast back to signed. At least for systems that use two's complement representation. However, tests for sign will often fail as the compiler assumes no overflow. Worse. it usually works as expected in debug mode. If, for some reason, you need to have defined behavior then do the casts and you will get it.